# How can I check whether the pptpd package is installed and remove it?

Tags: bash, shell

I need to check whether the RPM package pptpd is installed, ignoring the version.
If it is I want to remove it. If not then check whether /etc/pptpd.conf  and /etc/ppp/ exist. If yes for any or both then rm -rf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rpm -q pptpd
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
echo "pptpd installed.. removing"
rpm -e pptp
elif [ -e "/etc/pptpd.conf" ]
then 
rm -rf /etc/pptpd.conf
fi
```

But I wonder if you need it removed checking for the existence package/file is needed ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
if rpm --quiet -q pptpd    # check for package
then
   # the package does exist, remove it
   rpm -e pptpd
else
   # the package does not exist, so delete the files.
   /bin/rm -rf /etc/pptpd.conf /etc/ppp
```

Comment: well done both working fine one more thing if i want to display echo ip that assigned to eth1  any statement could help ?

Comment: I suggest you start a new question. Besides getting more answers, you will improve your point standing.